# Recursive Subroutine Reference

Tags: perl, recursion

I have tested the following code with perl 5.8 (codepad) and perl 5.16 . There's probably some deeper principle I'm missing and I'm curious what the logic behind this behavior is. Thanks.

The following simple recursive subroutine reference

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fact = sub {
    my $n = shift;
    if ($n == 0) {
         return 1;
    }
    return $n * $fact->($n-1);
};

print $fact->(100);
```

results in the error

```
Global symbol "$fact" requires explicit package name at line 9.
Execution aborted due to compilation errors.
```

declaring variable before defining it does not produce this error.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fact;
$fact = sub {
    my $n = shift;
    if ($n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return $n * $fact->($n-1);
};

print $fact->(100);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`my` *returns* the new lexical, so it can be used to assign *to* it in the same statement in which it was declared. However, any further references to that *name* only resolve to that lexical beginning with the next statement.

So separate the declaration:

```
my $fact;
$fact = sub { ... $fact ... }
```

This rule is in fact sometimes useful; you can have an outer lexical and an inner one and assign between the two:

```
my $foo = 42;
{
    my $foo = $foo;
    $foo += 42;
    print "foo is $foo\n";
}
print "foo is $foo\n";
```

If you have a recent version of Perl, you don't actually need to access `$fact` within the subroutine because the `__SUB__` pseudo-constant offers a reference to the current subroutine.

```
use 5.016;
my $fact = sub {
    my $n = shift;
    if ($n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return $n * __SUB__->($n-1);
};
```

Note that in the first example (where the `$fact` variable is used within the sub), a reference cycle is created, which might lead to Perl leaking memory over time. `__SUB__` is a fairly clean way to resolve that issue. (Other solutions to the problem include [the Y-combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator) and [reference weakening](http://search.cpan.org/~pevans/Scalar-List-Utils-1.41/lib/Scalar/Util.pm#weaken).)

Comment: Having used the Y-combinator for this type of problem, I can only say that I ♡ `__SUB__`.

Comment: It would be nice if this answer started with a big bold warning about the memory leak, rather than mentioning it as an afterthought.